# TFS2010: Opening certain Excel reports gives error TF80076

Tags: sharepoint, excel, tfs, reporting

When I try and open certain TFS2010 Excel reports I get the following error popup from Excel:

> TF80076: The data in the work item is
>   not valid or you do not have
>   permissions to modify the data. Please
>   correct the problem and retry.

[image: TF80076]

This is then followed by the popup:

> TF208103: The initialization of the
>   workbook to connect to Team Foundation
>   Server was not successful. THe
>   workbook will close.... etc. etc..

... and Excel closes.

The reports that throw this error include:

- **Documents -> Samples and Templates ->
  Project Management -> Document
  Template - Iteration Backlog.xlsm** (in
  fact all reports in this directory
  fail)
- **Documents -> Shared Documents ->
  Iteration 1 -> Issues.xlsx** (and all
  reports in this directory also fail)

I believe that the error may be misleading as this only happens under one project collection and this is a project collection I had some trouble setting up so it was recreated a couple of times. I suspect that the SharePoint site that hosts the reports has got out of sync with the project collection.

**Any ideas how to fix these errors?**

**Is there a way to regenerate the reports that error on the SharePoint site so that they can rebind with the project?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also another route to possible success, taken partially from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsprocess/thread/c449ba9a-f618-46c9-9365-d36ee4bc9a88/):

Open Visual Studio, choose Team -> Team Project Collection Settings -> Process Template Manager.  You can download the MSF 5 template to a folder on your hard drive.  Then navigate to

FOLDER YOU DOWNLOADED TO\MSF for Agile Software Development v5.0\Windows SharePoint Services\Shared Documents\Project Management\

Under this folder you will see the (now connectionless) Iteration Backlog.xlsm.

Open it & under "Team" choose "New List" & connect it to your Query "Iteration 1" or similar suitable Query.

Comment: FANTASTIC!! Worked like a charm. You are a genius, Pantelif. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

At the time the Team Project is generated those Excel sheets are also generated, pointing to "Iteration 1" Iteration (found at right-clicking Team Project, then "Team Project Settings">"Areas and Iterations...") & also referring to Work Item - Team Query "Iteration 1\Iteration Backlog".

If you managed to edit/delete those two, the Excel functionality shall be broken. Try to restore those back & the Excel shall work again. Then go to Excel Ribbon "Team" and choose "Configure\List" & set a valid query, pointing to a valid Iteration within your Team Project.

You can now delete the query, as well as the Team Project Iteration.

I had found this resolution [here](http://www.artiso.com/ProBlog/PermaLink,guid,c60dfcb4-cafb-489e-8edf-05350b0639f4.aspx) - (it's in German) & it was a lifesaver

Comment: Thanks Pantelif. I have checked that I have an Iteration 1 and the Interation Backlog query has not changed. Unfortunately, I still get the errors when opening the report. It is made worse by the fact Excel insists on closing the report after displaying the error so I can't alter anything on the "Team" tab. Is there maybe a way to stop Excel closing so I can check what the report is set to and edit if neccessary?

Comment: This had worked for me. I hope the other option (my second answer) works out better for you.

Comment: +1 for this answer as I believe this will help most people with this problem.

Comment: English translation: http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.artiso.com%2FProBlog%2FPermaLink%2Cguid%2Cc60dfcb4-cafb-489e-8edf-05350b0639f4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I also come across same issue. After trying following changes it started working.
Check from edit query in Azur if your query using variable like "@RecentProjectActivity" then replace it with other possible static references like you can refer some Area Path or any ID. Hope it will resolve your issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got this because the query Iteration 1/Iteration Backlog didn't work because I had change the iteration structure but not updated the query correspondingly.

So if you get this error, check that the query that the Excel list is using is working.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar problem when using @ macros like '@currentiteration'. 
Excel 2013 is not supporting importing Query with filters with macros to be added as List

Changing @currentiteration to absolute name of iteration resolved the issue